# web.py session does not work at all

Tags: python, session, web.py

I have do everything i can try, but it does not work at all. The problem is session.get('t_yname') always returns None when i check the session value.

Detail information here:

1. platform:max os x10.9.2
2. python: 2.7.3
3. web.py: 0.37 is the latest released version

Please help me.

I have tried creating session object in two ways:

1.create session using local disk:

```
global session
app = web.application(urls, globals())
if web.config.get('_session') is None:
    session = web.session.Session(app,web.session.DiskStore('sessions'),initializer=  {'t_yname': '', 't_auth':0})
    web.config._session = session
else: 
    session = web.config._session
```

2.with db

```
global session
app = web.application(urls, globals())

if web.config.get('_session') is None:
    store = web.session.DBStore(model.db, 'sessions')
    session = web.session.Session(app, store)
    web.config._session = session
else: 
    session = web.config._session
```

Some other code:

Set session value when user login (work as expected):

```
class Login:
    def GET(self):
        return render.login()
    def POST(self):
        name=web.input(name='').name
        passwd=web.input(passwd='').passwd
        if name=='' or passwd=='':
            raise web.seeother("/login")
        ep=str(hashlib.md5(passwd).hexdigest().lower())
        for user in t_globals['users'][:]:
            if name==str(user.name) and ep==str(user.passwd):
                session.t_auth=int(user.auth)
                session.t_yname=str(user.name)
                print "setted:" + session.get('t_yname')   ### work as expected here
                raise web.seeother("/")

        raise web.seeother("/login")
```

Check login by reading the session value(not work):

```
def check_login():
    login=False
    sname = session.get('t_yname')    ## always None
    print sname
    if sname is not None and sname != "":
        for user in t_globals['users'][:]:
            if str(user.name)==sname:
                login=True
        if login == False:
            session.t_yname=''
    return login
```

Comment: Can you describe the problem and possible errors a little more specific? It's hard to help if we don't know what doesn't work

Comment: uh, The problem is session.get('t_yname') always return None when i check the session value. As you see, i think i have saved  't_yname' value in POST method in the Login class. Thanks

Comment: I have tried session.t_yname not session.get('t_yname') before, but the result was worse bad. I got the error: AttributeError: 'ThreadedDict' object has no attribute 't_yname'

Answer (score 1):

Finnaly I solved the question. I use session._initializer['t_yname'] instead of session.t_yname. But i do not understand and the documents on [webpy.org](http://webpy.org/cookbook/sessions) do not mention this at all.